# How can I convert boost::asio::streambuf to float?

Tags: c++, boost, serial-port

I'm reading data from a serial port. I've managed to get the port setup, and can read into the buffer, but I can't figure out how to convert the data held by the buffer to a float.

```
float Serial::ReadData()
{
    boost::asio::streambuf buff;
    int bytesRead = read_until(*port, buff, "\n");
    boost::asio::const_buffers_1 constBuff = buff.data();
    char*data = nullptr;
    int pos = 0;
    for (auto buffer = constBuff.begin(); buffer != constBuff.end(); buffer++)
    {
        data[pos] = reinterpret_cast<char>(buffer);
        pos++;
    }
    buff.consume(bytesRead);
    return atof(data);
}
```

Comment: You didn't even specify what the streambuf contains. Is it binary? Ascii? base64? Compressed? IEEE raw bytes?'

Comment: I'm reading from bluetooth connected to a com port, so I believe it's sending raw bytes.

Comment: In that case your self-answer made no sense at all.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atof What's more, unless you know the exact wire format, nobody can actually answer. Note, my answer is doing logically the same as your `atof`. I'm going to go out on a limb and suggest that - obviously - you already found out that the format is textual representation.

Comment: It must be Ascii in that case.

Answer (score 0):

alternatively

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3363643f527cefaa)</kbd>**

For now it might look practically equivalent, but:

- it doesn't leak the memory
- it doesn't copy the buffer needlessly
- it handles error
- it is much more flexible should you want to parse more than 1 thing

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

struct Serial {
    float ReadData();

    boost::asio::serial_port* port = nullptr;
};

float Serial::ReadData()
{
    boost::asio::streambuf buff;
    /*int bytesRead = */read_until(*port, buff, "\n");
    std::istream is(&buff);
    float f;
    if (is >> f)
        return f;
    throw std::invalid_argument("ReadData");
}

int main(){}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, I figured out how to do it. It was much simpler than I had first thought.

```
float Serial::ReadData()
{
    boost::asio::streambuf buff;
    int bytesRead = read_until(*port, buff, "\n");
    char*data = new char[bytesRead];
    buff.sgetn(data, bytesRead);
    return atof(data);
}
```